# Is there a way to make a site that shows the data from multiple libraries in 1 view?

Tags: document-library, administration

At the company I am working with right now they have SharePoint 2010 and the current project has a lot of different libraries in different sites. Different users are responsible for adding documents to each library.

Is there a way to make a overview site for management to see a 30,000 foot view of the different libraries? Then they could see what work is being done without having to visit each site.

Answer (score 3):

Content by Query web part can be filtered in many ways. For example you can select all content in site , or filter by a certain content type (and its children). Since you have 3 filters this gives you a way to achieve what you ask

Comment: If you want more flexibility you can export the CQWP, edit the xml, and use the QueryOverride to define your own CAML query. (finish with save and import)